# ILShapes not drawn when added as a children to ILScreenObject

Tags: overlay, ilnumerics

I am generating image plot by setting the surface plot in 2d mode. I am trying to draw the overlay crosshair as an ILScreenObject and move it to jog/navigate
through the surface points along the wireframe.

But any shapes I add to the ILScreenObject are not visible other than the ILLabel?
I am using the following code.

```
        ILArray<float> specialData = ILSpecialData.sincf(20, 30);
        ILSurface surface = new ILSurface(specialData);
        surface.MouseClick += surface_MouseClick;
        ILPlotCube cube = new ILPlotCube();
        cube.Add(surface);

        //construct ILScreenobject
        ILScreenObject screenObj = new ILScreenObject();
        screenObj.Children.Add(new ILLabel("test label"));
        screenObj.Children.Add(Shapes.RectangleFilled);

        ilPanel1.Scene.Add(cube);
        ilPanel1.Scene.Camera.Add(screenObj);
        ilPanel1.Refresh();
```

All I could see with this code is a label centered on the image plot. Could anyone suggest me any possible solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. I'd suggest to create an issue here: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis

Comment: Just realized that If I set the width and height of the screenObject explicitly, then the shapes are shown.